# how can Activity call and refresh listciew in the previous Fragment?

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, refresh, call

I can use activity to call and refresh another activity's listview like below annd it work well

```
            Intent itn = new Intent(Activity.this, PreviousActivity.class).
                    setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(itn);
```

but now I have to use Add_Account activity to call a fragment like this...

```
            AccountFragment details = new AccountFragment();
            details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
```

it just pop up the AccountFragment on this activity without closing the Add_Account activity. and when I press 'back button' or add finish();. It didn't refresh my listview. What should I do?

this is the screenshots
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HYWSww9yTNAnlOF9AxTsufDu-GUyoei-0OXA5K4v5Ng/edit?usp=sharing